# Ruby: How to get symbol via a var that saves a string?

Tags: ruby

See the following code:

```
1  str1 = gets
2  str2 = "Hello"
3  puts str1
4  puts str1.to_sym().object_id()
5  puts str2.to_sym().object_id()
6  puts :"Hello".object_id()
```

In Line 1, I input "Hello" from stdin and save this string to var str1. In Line 2, I save a string "Hello" to var str2. Now str1 and str2 contains same string, although they are different string object, and their values are same. According to rule of symbol, I except I can get game symbol of "Hello" from str1 and str2. But output is:

```
Hello
213748
213548
213548
```

It looks that str1 has different symbol from str2. How can I get symbol of "Hello" from str1?

I ask this question because I'm facing a problem that, I need to input some words from stdin, then use these words as key to build a hash table. As hash table should use symbol as key to avoid memory waste, I need to get symbol of input words.

Comment: Don't use `to_sym()` and `object_id()`, just use `to_sym` and `object_id`. This is pretty key to writing Ruby that others will enjoy reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Now str1 and str2 contains same string, although they are different string object, and their values are same

Your assumptions are incorrect.

The symbols are different because the strings are different. The string from `gets` ends with a newline. You can prove this to yourself by inspecting the value of `:"Hello\n".object_id`.

Use [`strip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-strip) to remove the trailing newline, and both strings will be identical, and both will `to_sym` to the same symbol:

```
puts str1.strip.to_sym.object_id
```

Comment: Thx, you are right. Then it comes the other question. Since str1 contains "\n" already, why line 3 "puts str1" doesn't print an empty line? Dose puts eat "\n"?

Comment: No; it does put an empty newline though. I think you're misinterpreting the output. Try `puts "|#{str1}|"`

Comment: @EvanLi `puts` will add a newline to the output _unless there is already a newline as the last character_. So `puts "foo"` and `puts "foo\n"` have the same result. From [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-puts): _"Writes a record separator (typically a newline) after any that do not already end with a newline sequence."_

Answer (score 3):

@meagar is correct about the newline char, however you could also use [chomp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp).

To demonstrate here's an example session from irb:

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > without_chomp = gets
Hello
 => "Hello\n"
2.0.0p247 :002 > with_chomp = gets.chomp
Hello
 => "Hello" 
2.0.0p247 :003 > with_chomp_and_to_sym = gets.chomp.to_sym
Hello
 => :Hello
```